# Build VS2010 solution file from msbuild command line

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild

I want to build my VS2010 .sln file (projects are .net 4.0) with msbuild from the command line.  I expected this to work...

```
>C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/msbuild.exe application.sln
```

However I get this message:

`"Project file contains ToolsVersion="4.0", which is not supported by this version of MSBuild. Treating the project as if it had ToolsVersion="3.5"."`

The build continues but it can't find any of my references and fails.

I'm probably missing something obvious... any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
-dk

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This article maybe helpful: http://blog.prabir.me/post/Downgrading-VS2010-solutions-to-VS2008.aspx

And it seems it's not targeting proper msbuild version (error comes from 3.5 msbuild ver), try to open the Visual Studio 2010 command prompt, go to the solution directory and run msbuild.exe SolutionName.sln

Comment: the script I was running it from had a typo and indeed was calling the 3.5 msbuild.  Once I actually called the right exe it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

That's odd. Does VS2010 work OK? If not is the key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSBuild\ToolsVersions\4.0 missing? (Install bad.)

Verify the .sln version number at the top is 11.

Those are the only reasons I can think of.

Dan

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/177770/Creating-MSBuild-projects-from-sln-files) could be of some sort of help.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but usually on stackoverflow we prefer self-contained answer : links to references are fine, but the answer should be useful on its own. Links to external sites often end up being 404's after a few months, and it's a hassle to click on the link, then search through the page to find the relevant information.